# Python can't start new thread, but only a few alive threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I tried my best to search this issue on stackoverflow and google, but has no findings so far. The python program constantly runs into `Can't start new thread` issue. If I log out the active (alive) threads by `threading.enumerate()`, I see only a few, less than 10, threads. Is there a possibility that python run into `can't start new thread` even though only a small number of active thread?

Some guesses:

1. I don't name newly created threads. So the thread names increase, from thread-1 to thread-VERY-BIG-NUMBER. Is it possible that `VERY-BIG-NUMBER` is too big that exceeds system limit?
2. I use a python library called stopit (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stopit) to timeout some long time operation (REST requests). This library will raise an exception in an execution thread if it timeout. However, I only see <10 active threads when python throws `Can't start new thread`. Is it possible that some legacy thread is not terminated and running but doesn't show as alive thread?

Any help appreciated!

---

**Follow up and edit**

Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04

Minimum sample: This is a pretty big system, not able to post the whole system code here. Because I don't know the reason of this issue, I'm not able to come up with a short and reproducible sample program yet.

Comment: Can you please OS on which you are getting this error?

Comment: Check this it may solve your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283003/python-cant-start-new-thread-100-active-threads

Comment: What do you see with htop/top commands ? Also, it would help if you can post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Without providing a [mcve] and without access to the system in question, we can only play a guess game on what's the culprit as there can be dozens of them...

Comment: @zwer This is not true simply because there are not many possibilities, otherwise there are answers already. The *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable* rule is not applicable to all the questions universally, you need to understand the question before you make the judgement. If you don't agree, can you give an case of what caused the questioned scenario?

Comment: @Himal I didn't try htop/top. I will give it a try and get back. Thanks!

Comment: @DineshPundkar I do see this thread, it doesn't work for me. I see very stablely a small amount of thread from `ps -fLu` command.